# How to convert PIL image to wximage in Python 3

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, wxpython

Hours of searching keep turning up this code:

```
mywxImage = wx.EmptyImage(*size*)
myPILImageRGB = MyPILImage.convert('RGB')
myPILImageData = MyPILImageRGB.tostring()
mywxImage.SetData(myPILImageData)
```

But MyPILImageRGB doesn't seem to have a tostring() method.

What I'm trying to do is display images in a Python program without using an external application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use the *tostring* method at all.

This code converts a pil image to a bitmap and creates a wxImage on the way

```
def static_bitmap_from_pil_image(self, pil_image):
    wx_image = wx.Image(pil_image.size[0], pil_image.size[1])
    wx_image.SetData(pil_image.convert("RGB").tobytes())

    bitmap = wx.Bitmap(wx_image)
    static_bitmap = wx.StaticBitmap(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.NullBitmap)
    static_bitmap.SetBitmap(bitmap)
    return static_bitmap
```

Comment: Works, but I get "Call to deprecated item" on EmptyImage & BitmapFromImage

Comment: "Call to deprecated item EmptyImage. Use :class:`Image` instead." - I've updated the answer